# Xamarin - Replace QR code on TextChanged() Event

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, qr-code

I am writing a QR code app in Xamarin Forms that takes an input string in a text entry and converts it into a QR code. I would like the QR code to change dynamically while you are entering or deleting input in the text entry, similar to this website I found [here](https://www.the-qrcode-generator.com/).

I believe this is possible using `TextChangeEventArgs` but I am unsure how it all works. What am I missing here?

My text entry

```
var myEntry = new Entry
            {
                Text = "Hello SO"                    
            };
```

Here is my function to create a new barcode when `My Entry` is changed (it is not being called by anything yet)

```
void MyEntryChanged(Entry myEntry, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            barcode = new ZXingBarcodeImageView
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                AutomationId = "zxingBarcodeImageView",
            };
            barcode.BarcodeFormat = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
            barcode.BarcodeOptions.Width = 300;
            barcode.BarcodeOptions.Height = 300;
            barcode.BarcodeOptions.Margin = 10;
            barcode.BarcodeValue = myEntry.Text;

            Content = barcode;
        }
```

Comment: you may need to use Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread when updating the UI

Answer (score 0):

Since the MyEntryChanged event occurs in a different thread that your UI, the element Content is not present in that thread.

You should use the code like this:

```
void MyEntryChanged(Entry myEntry, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            barcode = new ZXingBarcodeImageView
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                AutomationId = "zxingBarcodeImageView",
            };
            barcode.BarcodeFormat = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
            barcode.BarcodeOptions.Width = 300;
            barcode.BarcodeOptions.Height = 300;
            barcode.BarcodeOptions.Margin = 10;
            barcode.BarcodeValue = myEntry.Text;

            Content = barcode;
        });

    }
```